# paypal html form shipping method

Tags: html, forms, variables, paypal

I currently have two shipping methods: 'express' and 'standard' in my shopping cart implementation. Is it possible to pass this information to PayPal using HTML variable?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [complete list](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables) with all variables you can send out to PayPal.
I read it quickly but did not find something like "shipping type" or similar. So you have to define it, on the custom field, where you can put any info you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However I already checked that page before posting the question and was wondering if I may have missed the variable somehow. I though it's unlikely that PayPal might have omitted a feature as basic as that. :(